# SSRS 2008 R2 Visibility Based on Report Parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am having some issues with dynamically changing report item visibility based on a report parameter.

Visibility is set correctly during the initial report run but WILL NOT change visibility of report items after the initial report run, regardless of if the report parameter changes. The expression I have on the `Hidden` attribute is below.

```
=IIF(Parameters!sr_emt_filter.Value = "ALL" And Parameters!sr_emt_direct_filter.Value = "ALL", True, False)
```

These are true report parameters and not query parameters. I currently have the parameters set to NEVER refresh the data sets as my process for this report is to pull all data on the first run and then use report parameters to filter down the results on an ad-hoc basis without re-querying the database (no need to discuss if this is a good approach or not, it is a requirement for what I am doing).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I figured this out. If I created a function in the report code and referenced the parameters in here it seems to work. Not really sure what the issue is but I got it working.

Comment: Hi thomas. I'm having the same problem and referencing my parameter in my report code (and nowhere else) didn't stop the re-querying. Did you discover any other relevant info?